# Download and start sh.x and .run files with curl or wget

Tags: bash, curl, sh, wget

Normally I start the bash programs from the terminal, with this command:

```
curl https://example.com/assets/file/file.sh | bash
```

But if i do the same thing with .run or .sh.x file it doesn't work.
I have tried in two different ways:

```
curl https://example.com/assets/file/file.sh.x | bash
```

Or

```
wget -O - https://example.com/assets/file/file.run | bash
```

I see a series of syntax errors or ascii codes in the terminal that do not allow the script to start.

On the web I have not found anything that can help me solve the problem.

Is it possible to solve this, or does the file extension not allow it?

wget output of file.sh.x file:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

-                                 [ <=>                                              ]  11.94K  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2020-03-28 16:03:19 (43.6 MB/s) - written to stdout [12224]

bash: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
bash: line 1: `ELF>@)@8  @@@@888      '
```

curl output of file.sh.x file:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 12224    0 12bash: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `)':--     0
2bash: line 1: `ELF>@)@8 @@@@888      '
24    0     0  39432      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 39432
(23) Failed writing body
```

file.sh.x content is something like:

```
...
    7f45 4c46 0201 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000
    0300 3e00 0100 0000 d00b 0000 0000 0000
    4000 0000 0000 0000 0029 0000 0000 0000
    0000 0000 4000 3800 0900 4000 1b00 1a00
    0600 0000 0400 0000 4000 0000 0000 0000
    4000 0000 0000 0000 4000 0000 0000 0000
    f801 0000 0000 0000 f801 0000 0000 0000
    0800 0000 0000 0000 0300 0000 0400 0000
    3802 0000 0000 0000 3802 0000 0000 0000
    3802 0000 0000 0000 1c00 0000 0000 0000
    1c00 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000
...
```

wget output of file.run:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/x-makeself]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

-                                 [ <=>                                              ]  12.86K  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2020-03-28 16:08:50 (44.6 MB/s) - written to stdout [13173]

Verifying archive integrity...head: cannot open 'bash' for reading: No such file or directory
main: line 80: bash: No such file or directory
Error in MD5 checksums: d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e is different from 42a127ab90433f4d3fabc166a4e0ca24
```

curl output of file.run:

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 13173    0 13173    0     0  32932      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 32932
Verifying archive integrity...head: cannot open 'bash' for reading: No such file or directory
main: line 80: bash: No such file or directory
Error in MD5 checksums: d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e is different from 42a127ab90433f4d3fabc166a4e0ca24
```

the content of the file.run file is quite long, there is all the initialization of the .run file and at the end a long list of ascii codes.

Run directly on the server they all work.

Using wget or curl commands don't work

Based on the response received, is there no way to automatically start sh.x / run files, as is the case with bash scripts by adding "| bash" to the end of the command?

Comment: Add content of `file.sh.x` to your question (no comment) and all errors.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: You really should be very careful about piping a sequence of unknown commands from a website into your shell!!!

The file you are trying to get `bash` to run is an [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) binary, i.e. a compiled executable program, not a shell script. You can check like this:

```
curl https://example.com/assets/file/file.sh.x > /tmp/unknown
file /tmp/unknown
```

Comment: So there is no way to automatically start a .sh.x file or a .run file? Anyway thanks for the warning, it's my file, I know what the content is.